# How to split two background color using Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I want to split two backgrounds using the blue one in the above and the bottom remains white. Using Constraint Layout, it is easy to make a horizontal guideline. However, I get stuck when I tried to split two background color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pccw.newmobileclient.ui.work_list.WorkListActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Appreciate any comment or advice. Thank you.

[image: Task view]

Comment: I don't know how you were trying to split that but you can use two `ImageView` or two children `ConstraintLayout` with background as color to do this.

Comment: Image updated, I want to have the search section in the above and the bottom section to be dynamic with search result or detail. But the point is I want to have a different background color in two sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare two views with different background colors based on **Guideline** to achieve that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline10"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I try to use View it also works.

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or Cmd+K to properly format your source code chunks.

Answer (score 0):

For background color like top blue and bottom white use gradient drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:endColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

and set this file as background for constraint layout..

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    tools:context="com.mycamera.Sample">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or Cmd+K to properly format your source code chunks.